# OpenCV HoughLines

Tags: python, opencv

Currently I'm working on a free-time project, which consists of parsing a video feed into a HTML template. In order to differentiate types of DOMs, I use 4 different angled lines in a rectangle (please ignore the triangle and the circle), but to calculate their angle, I must first find the lines. OpenCV's HoughLinesP comes in handy, but for whatever reason, it finds only a few lines.

Here are some sample images, on the left, that's the source image (with the found lines drawn on it, colored green), and on the left, that's the processed image. First, the source is converted to grayscale, then I run Canny on it. (I tried blurring it too)

[image: Sample images]

In my opinion only a small amount of lines are detected. This makes me question my threshold parameters. Currently, they are the following:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
```

And then for the line detection:

```
rho = 1.5
theta = pi / 180.
threshold = 60
min_line_length = 100
max_line_gap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(lineimage, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_length, max_line_gap)
```

Please note, that I'm only running edge/line detection on components which have a parent, that's why there are no lines detected on the most-outer component.

Am I doing something wrong? Are my parameters off the grid? I would greatly appreciate any suggestion on how to improve it!

Thank you in advance!